# Is arrow better than point in Arduino C?

Tags: oop, arduino, operators

I was looking at a SparkFun library that was modified by a person in order to add more functions and delete some unused ones, in order to learn more about library writing. What I don't get is why the parts with **->** in SF library were converted to **.** in this person library. For example:

```
while(!uart->available()){
```

was rewritten as

```
while(!uart.available()){
```

Also some calls to methods are changed:

```
uart->print(F("$$$"));
```

for

```
uart.print("$$$");
```

Is one way better than the other? More efficient? Has any effect at all?

Comment: This is covered in any C or C++ book, you should pick one up. In almost all cases, `x->y` is equivalent to `(*x).y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->` and `.` operators in c++ are similar, but not interchangeable. They both allow you to reference an object's members. However, the `.` only works when used with a real object, whilst the `->` only works when you have a pointer to an object.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Dog {
    public:
    void Bark() {
        std::cout << "Woof!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Dog spot;
    Dog * pointer_to_spot = & spot;

    spot.Bark();
    // spot->Bark(); // ERROR: spot cannot be dereferenced.

    pointer_to_spot->Bark();
    // pointer_to_spot.Bark(); // ERROR: pointer_to_spot is not an object.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for the example.